# Failing the whole Test Suite if one Test Case fails while running dependent test through VSTS

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have dependent test cases in my suite. If my first test fails it marks all other test as fail as well. So at the end it show that all all the test cases has failed which is not true.

Is there a way though which I can mark the test as 'failed due to dependent test failure' or something else so that it shows that it failed because the dependent test failed.
Is there a way to add a new state in test instead of only have pass, fail, not executed states.

I have added a common flag in our tests which marks the tests as failed when any dependent test fails.
As you can see in the code below.
It marks the test as Assert.Fail inside else part if the previous test has failed.
Is there a way to mark it in some other state and not failed for example : 'Failed due to dependent test failure'.

```
bool hasPreviousTestCasePassed = false
[TestMethod]
    public void DemoTest1()
    {
     try
        {
          ////perform all the test steps
          hasPreviousTestCasePassed = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            hasPreviousTestCasePassed = false;
        }
    }

 [TestMethod]
    public void DemoTest2()
    {
        try
        {
            if (hasPreviousTestCasePassed)
            {
              ///perform all the test steps and mark flag as true after all steps
             hasPreviousTestCasePassed = true;
            }
            else
            {    
               Assert.Fail("Execution for " + TestContext.TestName + " is aborted as the previous test case failed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            hasPreviousTestCasePassed = false;
        }
    }
```

Expected result would be to have a way to mark a test as Failed due to dependent test failure and not just mark it as failed.

The Idea behind doing this is that when my first test fails then it marks all the test as failed and the outcome says that all the test has been fail which is not actually true because they got executed.

So I want a way to show case the dependent failure in a separate state so that the results are more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider not using dependant tests at all, if possible.
I understand you need to execute some tests in a specific order because you need the program to be in a specific *state* before you can test some specific functionality.

What you could do is make your program under test load in a specific state, in which you can test specific functionality. This way, your tests will be independent from each other and could turn testing specific functions from taking hours into taking minutes.

I'm currently working on tests for a POS cash register. The cash register can produce documents like receipts, delivery notes, invoices, etc. To do specific tests on those type of documents, I just load a relevant document from db to work on, thus quickly getting that POS in a specific state. I made these documents prior to testing, the data is always the same, but highly configurable.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can make use of `TestContext.Properties` property to save the status of a particular test as a key-value pair. So, inside a particular test you'll create a pair: `TestContext.Properties.Add("testStatus", "Failed due to dependent test")`. 
And later on you will read the property as 
`string mystatus = TestContext.Properties["testStatus"].ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would `Assert.Inconclusive` help? [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.inconclusive)

It will make the distinction between a failing test and a 'suspicious test' due to previous failure obvious.

Comment: Yes it helps in Visual studio. But when I run test through VSTS(Azure Devops) It marks the test as failed. What I want is, a way to mark a test as skipped in VSTS